# How to use regexp to perform a glob in C/C++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, regex, glob

I need to match simple some simple glob patterns that include only * and ?. It occurred to me that I could transform the input pattern into a regexp - the only problem is I'm not familiar with regexp enough to know the replacements.

Essentially, I need an implementation for:

```
std::string getRexExpForGlob(const std::string& globPattern);
```

Note these matches aren't used for anything to do with the filesystem, so POSIX glob won't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your OS, you may have `<fnmatch>` with `int fnmatch(const char* pattern, const char* string, int flags)`.  This allows glob patterns against arbitrary strings, and a few extra flags to allow flexibility beyond that needed for filename matching.

Otherwise, glob's `*` and `?` are equivalent to regexp `.*` and `.` respectively.  (Globs can also have [] alternatives but you've said yours don't).

Comment: This solution is the simplest, thanks (fnmatch is good on my system).

Comment: fnmatch does not support 'alteration' (aka braces expansion)

Answer (score 2):

`*` in a glob pattern is equivalent to `.*` in regex.  `?` is equivalent to `.`.  In most regex dialects, `.` does not match a newline by default, and so if you need it to match that character, check your library for how to set that flag.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, `.` represents any single character. This maps to `?` in glob patterns. Similarly, `.*` represents any sequence of characters, which maps to `*` in glob patterns. You should be able to write a workable function from that.